# How to achieve tail call optimization while traversing tree-like structure using continuation-passing style

Tags: scala, recursion, tree, tail-call-optimization, continuation-passing

I try to implement tail call optimization to traverse tree-line structure using continuation-passing style in [scala](/questions/tagged/scala). Unfortunately my previous experience with [fsharp](/questions/tagged/fsharp) does not help much. I have recursive call w/o tail optimization:

```
def traverseTree(tree: Tree)(action: Int => Unit): Unit = {
  def traverseTreeRec(tree: Tree, continuation: () => Unit, action: Int => Unit): Unit = tree match {
    case Leaf(n) => {
      action(n)
      continuation()
    }
    case Node(n1, n2) => {
      traverseTreeRec(n1, () => traverseTreeRec(n2, continuation, action), action)
    }
  }
  traverseTreeRec(tree, () => (), action)
}
```

Afterwards I try to rewrite using `@annotation.tailrec` and `TailCalls`, but still not sure **how to decorate continuation**

```
def traverseTree(tree: Tree)(action: Int => Unit): Unit = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def traverseTreeRec(tree: Tree, continuation: () => TailRec[Unit], action: Int => Unit): TailRec[Unit] = tree match {
    case Leaf(n) => {
      action(n)
      continuation()
    }
    case Node(n1, n2) =>
      // how to properly implement tail call here?
      // ERROR: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
      traverseTreeRec(n1, () => tailcall(traverseTreeRec(n2, continuation, action)), action)
  }
  traverseTreeRec(tree, () => done(), action)
}
```

Thanks in advance

ps: [full sample on gist](https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/7615819)

Comment: The following question may be of use here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428868/how-to-use-tailcalls

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have an answer from Coursera discussion forum:

```
def traverseTree(tree: Tree)(action: Int => Unit): Unit = {
  def traverseTreeRec(tree: Tree, continuation: () => TailRec[Unit]): TailRec[Unit] = tree match {
    case Leaf(n) => {
      action(n)
      continuation()
    }
    case Node(n1, n2) =>
      tailcall(traverseTreeRec(n1,
        () => traverseTreeRec(n2,
          () => tailcall(continuation()))))
  }
  traverseTreeRec(tree, () => done(())).result
}
```

ps: [suggested question by @rob-napier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428868/how-to-use-tailcalls) contains some details why it should be applied in this way

Answer (score 0):

I have little knowledge of Scala but in your code I guess you can do:

```
tailcall(traverseTreeRec(n1, () => tailcall(traverseTreeRec(n2, continuation, action)), action))
```

Since the `tailcall` that were there were in fact in an other anonymous function it will call when hitting a leaf. Perhaps you need it in all tail positions:

```
def traverseTree(tree: Tree)(action: Int => Unit): Unit = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def traverseTreeRec(tree: Tree, continuation: () => TailRec[Unit], action: Int => Unit): TailRec[Unit] = tree match {
    case Leaf(n) => {
      action(n)
      tailcall(continuation())
    }
    case Node(n1, n2) =>
      tailcall(traverseTreeRec(n1, () => tailcall(traverseTreeRec(n2, continuation, action)), action))
  }
  tailcall(traverseTreeRec(tree, () => done(), action))
}
```

In Scheme it would have been faster just to let the recursion into the first branch not be a tail call and the second to be one but I guess you can't mix in Scala because it need trampolining to do TCO.

Comment: In my tests, the above code fails with the same error "could not optimize tailrec annotated method traverseTreeRec: it contains a recursive call not in tail position"

Comment: Looks like continuation should be `taillcall` instead of second `traverseTreeRec`: `tailcall(traverseTreeRec(n1, () => traverseTreeRec(n2, () => tailcall(continuation()))))`