# Is 'def eat():Unit = sleep(); def sleep(): Unit = eat()' a tail recursive function?

Tags: function, scala, recursion, tail-recursion

Two functions:

```
def eat(): Unit = sleep()
def sleep(): Unit = eat()
```

Both of them are recursive functions, because they called themselves in the body (indirectly), right?

But are they tail recursive functions?

Answer (score 6):

> Both of them are recursive functions, because they called themselves in the body (indirectly), right?

Yes, this is called [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).

> But are they tail recursive functions?

Yes, they are, as the call is the return value of the body. However, afaik the Scala compiler does not optimise these into `while` loops, it only does so for self-recursive functions. See [Does Scala support tail recursion optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1677419/1048572) for details, and [How to use TailCalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4428868/1048572) for a workaround.

Comment: To be precise: Scala only optimizes *direct tail-recursion*, when a method *directly* calls *itself* in *tail position*. This is a somewhat unfortunate consequence of wanting to stay interoperable with the host language, because the JVM's `GOTO` only allows you to jump to a target inside the same method. Note that in an object-oriented language it isn't actually immediately obvious whether or not a method calls "itself", because it might, for example, call a different overload or an overridden version.