# What is the difference between `scala.util.control.TailCalls.TailRec` and `scala.annotation.tailrec`?

Tags: scala, recursion

The scala standard library seems to offer two methods for ensuring a recursive function does not cause a stack overflow.

One is the `@tailrec` annotation, which supposedly causes the compiler to do something differently, or try extra hard to attempt tail recursion.

The other method is to actually change your function signature to return `TailRec[T]`, and then use the `TailCalls.done` and `TailCalls.tailcall` functions to wrap your return values.

What is the difference? Is there any reason at all to use `TailRec` when the compiler seems to be able to do it for me?

Comment: Echoing @MikeAllen's answer: `@tailrec` does _not_ cause the compiler to do anything differently except to terminate if the annotated method is _not_ tail recursive. If it _is_ tail recursive then there is no difference if the method is annotated or not. If it is _not_ tail recursive the compiler makes no attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@tailrec` annotation is a *tail recursion* guarantee. If a function annotated with `@tailrec` is not actually tail recursive, then compilation will fail. (Since a tail recursive function will not result in a stack overflow, this guarantee is particularly useful in production code.)

`scala.util.control.TailCalls` is a mechanism for implementing tail recursion using *trampolining* - refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428868/how-to-use-tailcalls) for more information.